# Embed a control inside a Tooltip in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, controls

is it possible to add a control to a tooltip?
What im trying to achieve is a tooltip that shows some example data in a dataGridview inside the tooltip.

What I have done so far is the following:

1. I have created a table with some settings (dataGridview with Name (text), Type (text), Example (image), and Setting (comboBox).

[image: ExampleImage]

2. I managed to show a tooltip with the example as string onMouseOver the example image.

I'd like to embed another dataGridview in the tooltip because some examples are in table form.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltips are very limited.

The solution is to create a custom tooltip. You do a form and make it look like a tooltip and you put on it what you want.

You can make it look exactly like a tooltip an you can show it and hide it with the event handlers on your datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use a custom panel that shows up on the cursors position and fade out after a timer has reached end.

Comment: You know, just simple protocol on SO, if someone takes the time to help me, I always make sure I let them know it was worth it! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's right, simply overlooked this one. It wasn't intentional.